# "I am going to start my job at Google from August, 2017", Is it correct?

Tags: grammar, expressions

I just received mail from new company (*i.e.* google) for acceptance, and I am going to start working from next month. (Actually, it is my first career.)

Is "I am going to start my job at Google from August, 2017" is it correct?" correct?
or would you please suggest me better expressions?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to ELU! Maybe [ELL](https://ell.stackexchange.com/) would be better for this type of question. Check the [help centre](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)for on topic questions here.

Comment: This is a situation where idiomatic choices are: "I am going to start my [new] job at Google in August" (add the year only if it's not the current one) or  "I will be working at Google from August". You can extend the second to "I've got a job – I will be working at Google from August". Mentioning that it's your 'first job' might be accurate and open but perhaps hints that you'd prefer to move elsewhere in the near future.

Comment: "start my job at Google in August 2017; or start my job at Google on August  7, 2017; or leave out "on" in the second (specific) formation.

Comment: There are many many ways of saying this, some more formal than others. If you are writing to a friend, you might say: *I've just been hired by Google, and they told me to start in August! Yay!!*

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I will start working at google in August.

You're expression is not wrong, but it's heavy on the tongue. Try to make your sentences simple and sharp.

No need for "2017", the reader will understand it's in the near future.

If you need to include "2017", then

I will start working at google on 1 Aug. 2017.